# Importing a type in a JSP results in "Only a type can be imported. com.sitename.ClassName resolves to a package"

Tags: java, jsp, maven, aem

I'm using maven to manage dependencies and building by installing the package to `/apps/myapp/install`. The maven build runs fine and installs. I've verified my bundle's registration and status as active in the `/system/console`

I've setup a component with the following markup in the jsp:

```
<%@page import="com.mysite.package.Constants" %>

<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <p>hi</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

When I don't have the import, the page loads fine when I hit a node under content with the sling:resourceType set to my component. However, when I do have the import, I get the following error `Only a type can be imported. com.mysite.package.Constants resolves to a package`. The code to my class is nothing fancy:

```
package com.mysite.package;
...
public class Constants {
  public static final String TEST = "hello";
}
```

I've added the following to my pom.xml to exclude packages that were unable to be resolved and to export my package:

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.2.0</version>
  <extensions>true</extensions>
  <configuration>
    <instructions>
      <Bundle-SymbolicName>com.mysite.package</Bundle-SymbolicName>
      <Export-Package>com.mysite.package.*</Export-Package>
      <Import-Package>!oracle.xml.*,!org.jaxen.*,!org.apache.felix.ipojo.*,!org.ow2.chameleon.syndication.*,!sun.io.*,!com.sun.image.codec.*,!bsh,!nu.xom,!org.apache.commons.beanutils.*,!org.apache.commons.configuration.*,!com.ibm.uvm.tools.*,!com.sun.jdmk.comm.*,!javax.jmdns.*,!javax.jms.*,*</Import-Package>
      <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency>
    </instructions>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

After doing so I was able to verify that my package and all of it's sub-folders were under the Exported packages section in the `/system/console` but I'm still seeing the error on import from the jsp. Is there something that I'm missing?

```
An error occurred at line: 6 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. com.mysite.package.Constants resolves to a package
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:388)
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.eval(DefaultSlingScript.java:171)
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:463)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:511)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:45)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:64)
  at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDeveloperModeFilter.doFilterWithErrorHandling(WCMDeveloperModeFilter.java:145)
  at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDeveloperModeFilter.doFilter(WCMDeveloperModeFilter.java:113)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
  at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilterWithErrorHandling(WCMDebugFilter.java:182)
  at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:149)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
  at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:252)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
  at com.day.cq.personalization.impl.TargetComponentFilter.doFilter(TargetComponentFilter.java:96)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:284)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.dispatchRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:324)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.SlingRequestDispatcher.dispatch(SlingRequestDispatcher.java:216)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.SlingRequestDispatcher.include(SlingRequestDispatcher.java:103)
  at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter$ForwardRequestDispatcher.include(WCMComponentFilter.java:431)
  at org.apache.jsp.libs.foundation.components.primary.cq.Page.Page_jsp._jspService(Page_jsp.java:106)
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:502)
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:449)
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.callJsp(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:265)
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.access$100(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:87)
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory$JspScriptEngine.eval(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:465)
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:361)
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.eval(DefaultSlingScript.java:171)
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.service(DefaultSlingScript.java:463)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.request.RequestData.service(RequestData.java:511)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.SlingComponentFilterChain.render(SlingComponentFilterChain.java:45)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:64)
  at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMDebugFilter.doFilter(WCMDebugFilter.java:146)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
  at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.filterRootInclude(WCMComponentFilter.java:357)
  at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMComponentFilter.doFilter(WCMComponentFilter.java:166)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
  at com.day.cq.personalization.impl.TargetComponentFilter.doFilter(TargetComponentFilter.java:96)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.processComponent(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:284)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.RequestSlingFilterChain.render(RequestSlingFilterChain.java:49)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:64)
  at com.adobe.granite.requests.logging.impl.RequestLoggerImpl.doFilter(RequestLoggerImpl.java:137)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
  at com.adobe.cq.social.commons.security.SaferSlingPostServlet.doFilter(SaferSlingPostServlet.java:121)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
  at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.doFilter(AuthoringUIModeServiceImpl.java:349)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
  at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.warp.TimeWarpFilter.doFilter(TimeWarpFilter.java:106)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
  at com.day.cq.wcm.mobile.core.impl.redirect.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:295)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.debug.RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.doFilter(RequestProgressTrackerLogFilter.java:64)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
  at com.adobe.cq.social.commons.cors.CORSAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(CORSAuthenticationFilter.java:91)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
  at com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.impl.FormsHandlingServlet.doFilter(FormsHandlingServlet.java:251)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
  at com.day.cq.theme.impl.ThemeResolverFilter.doFilter(ThemeResolverFilter.java:76)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
  at com.adobe.granite.optout.impl.OptOutFilter.doFilter(OptOutFilter.java:74)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
  at com.day.cq.wcm.core.impl.WCMRequestFilter.doFilter(WCMRequestFilter.java:90)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
  at com.adobe.cq.history.impl.HistoryRequestFilter.doFilter(HistoryRequestFilter.java:107)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
  at com.day.cq.wcm.designimporter.CanvasPageDeleteRequestFilter.doFilter(CanvasPageDeleteRequestFilter.java:88)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
  at org.apache.sling.rewriter.impl.RewriterFilter.doFilter(RewriterFilter.java:83)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
  at com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter.doFilter(InnerCacheFilter.java:77)
  at com.adobe.granite.httpcache.impl.InnerCacheFilter.doFilter(InnerCacheFilter.java:56)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
  at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:128)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
  at com.adobe.cq.dam.s7imaging.impl.auth.MemoryTokenAuthHandler.doFilter(MemoryTokenAuthHandler.java:156)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
  at org.apache.sling.bgservlets.impl.BackgroundServletStarterFilter.doFilter(BackgroundServletStarterFilter.java:135)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
  at com.adobe.granite.resourceresolverhelper.impl.ResourceResolverHelperImpl.doFilter(ResourceResolverHelperImpl.java:81)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.filter.AbstractSlingFilterChain.doFilter(AbstractSlingFilterChain.java:60)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingRequestProcessorImpl.doProcessRequest(SlingRequestProcessorImpl.java:153)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.SlingMainServlet.service(SlingMainServlet.java:205)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:339)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:300)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.ServletPipeline.handle(ServletPipeline.java:93)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:50)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
  at org.apache.sling.i18n.impl.I18NFilter.doFilter(I18NFilter.java:128)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
  at org.apache.sling.security.impl.ReferrerFilter.doFilter(ReferrerFilter.java:290)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
  at com.adobe.granite.license.impl.LicenseCheckFilter.doFilter(LicenseCheckFilter.java:298)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
  at org.apache.felix.http.sslfilter.internal.SslFilter.doFilter(SslFilter.java:55)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
  at org.apache.sling.featureflags.impl.FeatureManager.doFilter(FeatureManager.java:115)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
  at org.apache.sling.engine.impl.log.RequestLoggerFilter.doFilter(RequestLoggerFilter.java:75)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.doHandle(FilterHandler.java:108)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.handler.FilterHandler.handle(FilterHandler.java:80)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.InvocationFilterChain.doFilter(InvocationFilterChain.java:46)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.HttpFilterChain.doFilter(HttpFilterChain.java:31)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.FilterPipeline.dispatch(FilterPipeline.java:76)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.dispatch.Dispatcher.dispatch(Dispatcher.java:49)
  at org.apache.felix.http.base.internal.DispatcherServlet.service(DispatcherServlet.java:67)
  at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:684)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:501)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:229)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1086)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:428)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:193)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1020)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:135)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:255)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:116)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:370)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.handleRequest(AbstractHttpConnection.java:494)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:971)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(AbstractHttpConnection.java:1033)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:644)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:235)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.server.AsyncHttpConnection.handle(AsyncHttpConnection.java:82)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.handle(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:667)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint$1.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:52)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:608)
  at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:543)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP: 

An error occurred at line: 6 in the generated java file
Only a type can be imported. com.mysite.package.Constants resolves to a package
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.DefaultErrorHandler.javacError(DefaultErrorHandler.java:92)
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.ErrorDispatcher.javacError(ErrorDispatcher.java:330)
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.JDTCompiler.generateClass(JDTCompiler.java:421)
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:312)
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:290)
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:277)
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:501)
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.prepareServlet(JspServletWrapper.java:427)
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:486)
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:449)
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.callJsp(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:265)
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory.access$100(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:87)
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.jsp.JspScriptEngineFactory$JspScriptEngine.eval(JspScriptEngineFactory.java:465)
  at org.apache.sling.scripting.core.impl.DefaultSlingScript.call(DefaultSlingScript.java:361)
  ... 146 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Did you try `com.mysite.package.Constants.*`? The error is very clear that `"com.mysite.package.Constants resolves to a package"` not a class.

Comment: Yes, that will prevent an error but it won't allow for proper usage. The issue is that com.mysite.package.Constants is a class so I'm thinking the error might be something more involved. I will update the question with the code.

Comment: Post the whole stack trace. That error message has no context.

Comment: Is your bundle active or is it just registered. If it's only registered, you wont have access to the classes.

Comment: In the `/system/console` it says that it's active under the **Status** column. I've also specified the artifactId as a dependency as well as an embedded in the pom.xml of packaging type content-package for the jcr folders that we are uploading (apps and etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was due to a missing dependency and was resolved by adding the following to the parent pom of the project:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
  ...
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.adobe.granite.bundles</groupId>
      <artifactId>json</artifactId>
      <version>20090211_1</version>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
...
<dependencies>
...
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.adobe.granite.bundles</groupId>
    <artifactId>json</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```